# Removing useless tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, edits, tags

Today, I answered a question that was tagged noob-question. After answering, I decided noob-question does not carry any useful information. But then I discovered there was 70 question tagged this way, and 300 or more question tagged newbie.

Do you think it is a good edit to remove uninformative tag?
Do you think such tags are somehow useful?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/tag-cleanup-request-please-get-rid-of-beginner If we go by that, then newbie should just be retagged as beginner.

Comment: It should be retagged beginner, just like `newbie` was in August 2009 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12915/please-retag-newbie-to-beginner

Comment: Honestly, I think anyone tagging a question with something as decidedly derogatory as `noob-question` should be sanctioned by mods.

Comment: @State - a quick scan of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/noob-question seems to show most are tagged as such by the OP.

Comment: Self tagging as [n00b] is presumably a defensive measure: they don't want to get flamed. And though I see few attacks on beginners for being beginners the tenor of the sites can still sometimes be a little rough on people posting poorly constructed questions---who are mostly beginners. So a glance over the front page *could* cause a new user to feel it was better to take defensive measures.

Comment: I merged both `noob-question` and `newbie` into the `beginner` tag.

Comment: @Dominic: Thanks; didn't look (uh, obviously) this morning. But why on the good earth would someone tag his *own* question that way?

Comment: @State: it's kind of self-deprecating.  consider a long-time C hacker just starting to learn .Net.  this fellow might use the *[noob-question]* when he knows what he's asking is a beginner question, but he's stuck and needs to ask anyway.

Comment: @State: why not? people are okay with buying themselves "X for dummies" books. sometimes you know that you don't know enough. i don't even consider "noob" offensive/deprecating. i've used "newbie" on some of my own questions. it lets people know that you're asking something that you think should be simple but you just can't figure it out

Comment: @Kip, @~quack: Guess so. Still, it's not a particularly useful tag, and its purpose is served by the `beginner` tag equally well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think at this time, `beginner` is the most popular of that type of tag, and it is also the least offensive, so I say all tags like that should be merged into `beginner`

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a good edit to remove uninformative tags.

Tags should be used to specify the content of the post, not as derogatory uses targeting the user, and IMHO not to specify the complexity level of the question.